# SharePoint Development Newbie

Tags: sharepoint-addin

Just a general SharePoint development question. I am new to developing for this platform and have spent the last few weeks reading blog posts and cant find much consistency on best practices.  I am developing for Sharepoint Online not on-premise. In Visual Studio should I be using the "Sharepoint Add-in" template and create an "App Part" or the "SharePoint 2013 Visual Webpart" template and create solution package to deploy? Seems that the Visual web part has less limitations than an app part but might be depreciated with SharePoint Online?  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: For Online your only valid option is to use the "Add-in" template

Comment: Thanks Robert.  Do you have any links to good examples or Github projects as reference. I am stumbling on the same Google results at this point.

Comment: http://dev.office.com/ is the best way to get started. It is a steep hill in the beginning to get a grip on the development model, but there is tons of samples there. And this community has a lot of help as well (when you have started and are running in to specific problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use App Parts. Visual Webparts utilize server side code, which you can't install on SP Online (briefly, the way that App Parts get around this is that they have you install the server side code at a remote location like an Azure Cloud site and then add an iFrame to the page).